# Clean yarn test cache

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I have a file (`oldFile-test.js`) with a test case in it, and run `yarn test`. I then change the name of the file to `newFile-test.js` and run `yarn test` again. I get an error:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/path/to/__tests__/oldFile-test.js'`

How would I tell the yarn test runner to not look for `oldFile-test.js` anymore? The command `yarn cache clean` doesn't help.

Comment: may be is yarn test defined in your package.json under scripts? and there still the name oldfile-test.js written :-/

Comment: Nope, I searched all files in my project for the string that contains my old filename, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to **clear cache of tests**

command for YARN is **`yarn test --clearCache`**

command for NPM is **`npx jest --clearCache`**

run the above command in terminal inside the root directory of project

if above method not working so just run:

```
jest --clearCache
```

**If you have already installed Jest as a dependency in your project** and if the above jest command is not working so just **create a new script in the package.json file** of your project

```
{
...

    "scripts:" {
        "clear_jest": "jest --clearCache"
    }
... 

}
```

And then run below command in terminal

**npm run clear_jest**

Answer (score -1):

What file `yarn test` calls is defined in the 'scripts' section of package.json. Hence you have to change the file name there.

cf. https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/test/